# SOLR Parallel SQL: GROUP BY throws exception

Tags: sql, solr

This query works as expected:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM donation
```

Adding GROUP BY:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM donation GROUP BY people_person_id
```

Now I get response:

```
{
  "result-set":{
    "docs":[{
        "EXCEPTION":"Failed to execute sqlQuery 'SELECT sum(amount) as total  FROM donation GROUP BY people_person_id' against JDBC connection 'jdbc:calcitesolr:'.\nError while executing SQL \"SELECT sum(amount) as total  FROM donation GROUP BY people_person_id\": null",
        "EOF":true,
        "RESPONSE_TIME":279}]}
}
```

`people_person_id` field exists, stored, docValues=true.

Any ideas on  what is causing this? Or how to debug?

Here is the collection structure:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="people_person_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
<field name="group_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="amount" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" docValues="true"/>
```

Comment: Your error says `GROUP BY group_id`, not `GROUP BY people_person_id`.

Comment: I apologise. That was a mistake, I copied the wrong response. I edited the original post.

Comment: Which version of Solr?

Comment: Version - 7.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joel Bernstein at SOLR mailing list. The problem here is that the SQL statement doesn't meet the syntax standard. The query should be:

```
SELECT people_person_id, sum(amount) as total FROM donation GROUP BY
people_person_id
```

In other words, column that you're grouping on should be present in the SELECT.

SOLR should of course respond with a proper error message and not 'null' in such cases since this is a perfectly working SQL query for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between the query shown by you and query shown in message.

**Your Query :** 
SELECT sum(amount) as total FROM donation GROUP BY people_person_id

**Query Shown in Message:**
SELECT sum(people_person_id) as total  FROM person GROUP BY group_id

The query which you wrote is absolutely correct, however the query shown in message may not give you the desired result if "people_person_id" is not any number, but a character.

Please post your table structure on which you are running query

Comment: I apologise. That was a mistake, I copied the wrong response. I edited the original post. Also added the collection structure.